# nested form for has_many association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

A User has_many emails. How can I create a new `User` and have a single new `Email` nested in the form?

**user_controller.ex**

```
[...]
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
[...]
```

**form.html.eex**

```
[...]
<%= inputs_for f, :emails, fn ef -> %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label ef, :value, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input ef, :value, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag ef, :value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
[...]
```

There are a couple of Stackoverflow questions about this but none fixes this simple problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller, use `Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc/4`:

```
alias MyApp.Email

[...]

changeset =
  User.changeset(%User{})
  |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:emails, [%Email{}])
render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
```

This will create one empty `%Email` with default values and put it in the `:emails` association of the changeset.

Comment: How would one do it if they wanted to submit more than one email?